# Compute Galois group

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Compute the Galois group $Gal\left(\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)/\mathbb{Q}\right)$ and Galois group of a normal closure of $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[5]{7}\right)/\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: What have you tried so far? :-) Hint: Are those extension normal and which degree do they have? If an extension is Galois, then the degree equals the order of the Galois group.

Comment: $\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right):\mathbb{Q}\right]=2$ and $\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt[5]{7}\right):\mathbb{Q}\right]=5$

Comment: What should we do next?

Comment: For the first case: which groups of order $2$ do you know?

Comment: Do you imply $S_{2}$?

Comment: This in fact is the only group of order $2$, so you have the answer for the first question. For the second: Is this a normal extension?

Comment: For group of order $5$ I know $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$

Comment: Please give me more details. :)

Comment: In fact, your field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{7}) | \mathbb{Q}$ is not normal. Therefore you cannot speak of a Galois group. You could speak either of the autormorphism group of that extension *or* of the Galois group of a normal closure of that field.

Comment: I think the question is now having the appropriate context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already noticed, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) | \mathbb{Q}$ is a quadratic extension and hence normal. The Galois group is then the unique group of order $2$, $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Your field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{7}) | \mathbb{Q}$ is not normal. Therefore you cannot speak of a Galois group. You could speak either of the autormorphism group of that extension *or* of the Galois group of a normal closure of that field. You have to specify what you mean.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: So it is up to you to determine the normal closure! Hint: What is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[5]{7}$ and what are it's roots?

Comment: Can you explain more precisely to me?

Comment: For computing the Galois group of a normal closure of your extension you could try to find the minimal polynomial. What does normal in terms of the minimal polynomial mean?

Comment: The other field is missing elements needed for the fifth roots of unity. We can fix it as follows: Either $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[5]{7},e^{2\pi i/5}]$ or equivalently $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[5]{7},i,\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}]$. Then all roots of $x^5-7=0$ are there.